# regex to match line breaks and tabs between brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove line breaks and tabs from content that's inside brackets from data like this:

```
settings:a [
    a:[
        a:a
        b:b
    ]
    b:[
        a:a
        b:b
    ]
]

settings:b [
    a:[
        a:a
        b:b
    ]
]
```

So it becomes:

```
settings:a [ a:[ a:a b:b ] b:[ a:a b:b ] ] 
settings:b [ a:[ a:a b:b ] ]
```

The regex i'm using `\n(?=[^\[\]]*\])` works to some extent but I don't get the output like above. Can you help?

[Regex Example](https://regex101.com/r/5bJwx1/1)

Comment: while this works with regex, you should consider doing it with php. If you look at the regex in a few months... or worse - if a colleague looks at the regex in a few months, he won't get, what you've done there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex with `preg_replace` (so, a single regex pass will do):

```php
[\t\n]+(?=[^][]*(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])[^][]*)*])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5A1T45/1). Details:

- `[\t\n]+` - one or more tab or newline chars (use `\s` if you need to match *any* whitespace, and also add `u` modifier flag if you need to handle Unicode texts)
- `(?=[^][]*(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])[^][]*)*])` - a positive lookahead that requires its patterns to match immediately to the right of the current location:

  - `[^][]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
  - `(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])[^][]*)*` - zero or more occurrences of

    - `(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])` - Group 1 (technical, necessary for recursion to work): a `[`, then any substring between paired nested `[` and `]` and then a `]`
    - `[^][]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
  - `]` - a `]` char.

See [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/aQ3eq):

```php
$re = '/[\t\n]+(?=[^][]*(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])[^][]*)*])/';
$str = "settings:a [\n  a:[\n       a:a\n       b:b\n   ]\n b:[\n       a:a\n       b:b\n   ]\n]\n\nsettings:b [\n  a:[\n   \n\na:a\n       b:b\n   ]\n]";
echo preg_replace($re, ' ', $str);
// => settings:a [ a:[ a:a b:b ] b:[ a:a b:b ] ]
//    settings:b [ a:[ a:a b:b ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this recursive regex in `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$s = 'settings:a [
    a:[
        a:a
        b:b
    ]
    b:[
        a:a
        b:b
    ]
]';

echo preg_replace_callback('/\[(?:([^][]*)|(?R))*\]/', function ($m) {
      return preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $m[0]); }, $s) . "\n";
```

**Output:**

```
settings:a [ a:[ a:a b:b ] b:[ a:a b:b ] ]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5bJwx1/2)